# Join values from one column to the another with replacing the second line in a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two columns and want to join values from one column to the other. I want to join values from column "A" to column "B", but at the and I want in column "B" for each cell to be with two lines if a cell from column "B" is not empty and only with value from column "A" if a cell in column "B" is empty.

Here is data frame

df

```
  A      B
  Nr.1  18b
  Nr.1  
  Nr.1  18c\nNr.2\n
  Nr.1  18d\nNr.1
  Nr.2  
  Nr.2  20a\n
  Nr.2  20a\nNr.2
  Nr.3  20b\nNr.2\n
  Nr.3
```

So, at the and I want:

df

```
  A      B
  Nr.1  18b\nNr.1
  Nr.1  Nr.1
  Nr.1  18c\nNr.1
  Nr.1  18d\nNr.1
  Nr.2  Nr.2
  Nr.2  20a\nNr.2
  Nr.2  20a\nNr.2
  Nr.3  20b\nNr.2
  Nr.3  Nr.3
```

I tried with df['B'] = df[["B", "A"]].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1) when I want to add values from column "A" and it works when the cell from column "B" ends with newline (\n)

When I do not have the newline at the end of string then I use df['B'] = df[["B", "A"]].apply(lambda x: '\n'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)),axis=1)

But the problem is when I already have two lines in the cell. I need to replace a value in the second line with the value from column "A", and at the end of the string should not be "\n".

Is it some elegant way to solve this?
I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with indexing for select first values of lists, add separator and column `A` and last replace missing values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['B'] = (df['B'].str.split('\\').str[0] + '\\n' + df['A']).fillna(df['A'])
print (df)
      A          B
0  Nr.1  18b\nNr.1
1  Nr.1       Nr.1
2  Nr.1  18c\nNr.1
3  Nr.1  18d\nNr.1
4  Nr.2       Nr.2
5  Nr.2  20a\nNr.2
6  Nr.2  20a\nNr.2
7  Nr.3  20b\nNr.3
8  Nr.3       Nr.3
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I will check later in detail because I have some problems ("\n" appears in cells). But I think that I understand your solution.

Comment: It works for me when I split with ("\\n") and add with "\n"...I have a question regarding the number of lines that I want to keep, in this case, it is only one (the first), and you wrote: .str[0], but if I want (hypothetical) to keep first two lines, what I should do? I mean, when I split, I have a list, and how to convert that list to lines with delimiter "\n"?

Comment: I think then use `.str[:2].str.join('\\n')`

Comment: Aha. Thank you. Then, join is necessary...aha, that was the point...thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
# 1 - you split column B and keep only the first part    
df["B"] = df["B"].str.split(pat='\\', expand=True)[0]

# 2 - you concatenate the 2 columns separated with a \n
df["B"] = df.B + '\n' + df.A

# 3 - the second step didn't work when columns B is empty, so you use loc to replace the NaN with the value of column A
df.loc[df.B.isna(), 'B'] = df.loc[df.B.isna(), 'A']
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I understand your solution, it is the same logic as with jezrael solution.